# RxJava: how to compose multiple Observables with dependencies and collect all results at the end?

Tags: java, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm learning RxJava and, as my first experiment, trying to rewrite the code in the first `run()` method in [this code](https://gist.github.com/benjchristensen/4671081) (cited on [Netflix's blog](http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/02/rxjava-netflix-api.html) as a problem RxJava can help solve) to improve its asynchronicity using RxJava, i.e. so it doesn't wait for the result of the first Future (`f1.get()`) before proceeding on to the rest of the code.

`f3` depends on `f1`. I see how to handle this, `flatMap` seems to do the trick:

```
Observable<String> f3Observable = Observable.from(executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceA()))
    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call(String s) {
            return Observable.from(executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceC(s)));
        }
    });
```

Next, `f4` and `f5` depend on `f2`. I have this:

```
final Observable<Integer> f4And5Observable = Observable.from(executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceB()))
    .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call(Integer i) {
            Observable<Integer> f4Observable = Observable.from(executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceD(i)));
            Observable<Integer> f5Observable = Observable.from(executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceE(i)));
            return Observable.merge(f4Observable, f5Observable);
        }
    });
```

Which starts to get weird (`merge`ing them probably isn't what I want...) but allows me to do this at the end, not quite what I want:

```
f3Observable.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(String s) {
        System.out.println("Observed from f3: " + s);
        f4And5Observable.subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer i) {
                System.out.println("Observed from f4 and f5: " + i);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

That gives me:

```
Observed from f3: responseB_responseA
Observed from f4 and f5: 140
Observed from f4 and f5: 5100
```

which is all the numbers, but unfortunately I get the results in separate invocations, so I can't quite replace the final println in the original code:

```
System.out.println(f3.get() + " => " + (f4.get() * f5.get()));
```

I don't understand how to get access to both those return values on the same line. I think there's probably some functional programming fu I'm missing here. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want `toList`?

Answer (score 19):

It looks like all you really need is a bit more encouragement and perspective on how RX is used.  I'd suggest you read more into the documentation as well as marble diagrams (I know they're not always useful). I also suggest looking into the `lift()` function and operators.

- The entire point of an observable is to concatenate data flow and data manipulation into a single object
- The point of calls to `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` are to manipulate the data in your data flow
- The point of merges are to combine data flows
- The point of operators are to allow you to disrupt a steady stream of observables and define your own operations on a data flow. For example, I coded a moving average operator. That sums up `n` `double`s in an Observable of doubles to return a stream of moving averages. The code literally looked like this

  `Observable movingAverage = Observable.from(mDoublesArray).lift(new MovingAverageOperator(frameSize))`

You'll be a relieved that a lot of the filtering methods that you take for granted all have `lift()` under the hood.

With that said; all it takes to merge multiple dependencies is:

- changing all incoming data to a standard data type using `map` or `flatMap`
- merging standard data-types to a stream
- using custom operators if one object needs to wait on another, or if you need to order data in the stream. Caution: this approach will slow the stream down
- using to list or subscribe to collect all of that data

Comment: I appreciate the response. I hope to get back to playing with RxJava someday soon.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:** someone converted the following text, which I had added as an edit on the question, into an answer, which I appreciate, and understand may be the proper SO thing to do, however *I do not consider this an answer because it's clearly not the right way to do it*. I would not ever use this code nor would I advise anyone to copy it. **Other/better solutions and comments welcome!**

---

I was able to solve this with the following. I didn't realize you could `flatMap` an observable more than once, I assumed results could only be consumed once. So I just `flatMap` f2Observable twice (sorry, I renamed some stuff in the code since my original post), then `zip` on all the Observables, then subscribe to that. That `Map` in the `zip` to aggregate the values is undesirable because of the type juggling. **Other/better solutions and comments welcome!** The [full code is viewable in a gist](https://gist.github.com/skehlet/9418379). Thank you.

```
Future<Integer> f2 = executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceB());
Observable<Integer> f2Observable = Observable.from(f2);
Observable<Integer> f4Observable = f2Observable
    .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println("Observed from f2: " + integer);
            Future<Integer> f4 = executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceD(integer));
            return Observable.from(f4);
        }       
    });     

Observable<Integer> f5Observable = f2Observable
    .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Integer> call(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println("Observed from f2: " + integer);
            Future<Integer> f5 = executor.submit(new CallToRemoteServiceE(integer));
            return Observable.from(f5);
        }       
    });     

Observable.zip(f3Observable, f4Observable, f5Observable, new Func3<String, Integer, Integer, Map<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> call(String s, Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("f3", s);
        map.put("f4", String.valueOf(integer));
        map.put("f5", String.valueOf(integer2));
        return map;
    }       
}).subscribe(new Action1<Map<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Map<String, String> map) {
        System.out.println(map.get("f3") + " => " + (Integer.valueOf(map.get("f4")) * Integer.valueOf(map.get("f5"))));
    }       
});
```

And this yields me the desired output:

```
responseB_responseA => 714000
```

Comment: I learn this technique from you! it works well but I wonder if there is even a "cleaner" way to handle this common situation.

Comment: I have 2 observable dependent on each other, observable 2 is dependent on observable 1, so observable 1 should execute before observable 2 and then I need to combine the result of both observable. Do we have any operator for this. Can zip do this job. I do not want to use flatMap because it converts one stream into another but here I need to set dependency and then zip the result. Please reply.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is switchmap. We ran into a similar issue where   we have a session service that handles getting a new session from an api, and we need that session before we can get more data. We can add to the session observable that returns the sessionToken for use in our data call.

getSession returns an observable;

```
public getSession(): Observable<any>{
  if (this.sessionToken)
    return Observable.of(this.sessionToken);
  else if(this.sessionObservable)
    return this.sessionObservable;
  else {
    // simulate http call 
    this.sessionObservable = Observable.of(this.sessonTokenResponse)
    .map(res => {
      this.sessionObservable = null;
      return res.headers["X-Session-Token"];
    })
    .delay(500)
    .share();
    return this.sessionObservable;
  }
}
```

and getData takes that observable and appends to it.

```
public getData() {
  if (this.dataObservable)
    return this.dataObservable;
  else {
    this.dataObservable = this.sessionService.getSession()
      .switchMap((sessionToken:string, index:number) =>{
        //simulate data http call that needed sessionToken
          return Observable.of(this.dataResponse)
          .map(res => {
            this.dataObservable = null;
            return res.body;
          })
          .delay(1200)
        })
        .map ( data => {
          return data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("err in data service", err);
         // return err;
        })
        .share();
    return this.dataObservable;
  }
}
```

You will still need a flatmap to combine the not dependent observables.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hiA1jP?p=info

Where I got the idea to use switch map: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! It's been so long since I last looked at RxJava I really can't tell if I should make this the accepted answer. Definitely upvoted though.